# How to create a time range picker view as native (Android/iOS) or React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to create a time picker view like below. Is there a library to implement this type of view in Android, iOS, or in React native?

You can refer to the draggable time picker in [Doodle](https://doodle.com/create#week):

[image]

#### What I am done so far

I do a lot of search, but I didn't find any library related to this. So I decided to create one myself. But there are lot of issues.

My solution is to create a RecyclerView with DrawingView. I managed to create that drag, but it doesn't sync with RecyclerView. The scrolling is not working. And I am not getting a correct child view, etc. The code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawingView dv;
    private Paint mPaint;
    RecyclerView mListView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dv = new DrawingView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout view = findViewById(R.id.contentView);
        setRecyclerView();

        // RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 1000);
        // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        // dv.setLayoutParams(params);

        view.addView(dv);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.parseColor("#009999"), Color.parseColor("#009999"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(90);
        mPaint.setTextSize(10);

    }

    private void setRecyclerView(){
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mListView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter());
    }

    private float getHeight(){
        return this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public  int height;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;
        private float mX, mY;
        private Paint mTextPaint;
        private float mYmax, mYmin, mYStart;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 10;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context = c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);

            mTextPaint = new Paint();
            mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mTextPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);

            mTextPaint.setTextSize(20);
            int mWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            mX = mWidth/2;
            // mX = 50;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
            canvas.drawPaint(mTextPaint);
        }

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mYmax = mYmin = mYStart = y;
            mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(mX, y);
            //  mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x,  float y) {

            float dy = y - mY;
            if (Math.abs(dy) >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                if (mYmax == 0 && mYmin == 0){
                    mYmax = y;
                    mYmin = y;
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, mX, (y + mY)/2);
                } else if (dy < 0) {
                    if (mYmax > y){
                        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                        mPath.reset();
                        mPath.moveTo(mX, mYmin);
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mYmin, mX, (y + mY)/2);
                        if (mYmax > mYStart)
                            mYmax = y;
                        else
                            mYmax = mYStart;
                    }
                    else {
                        mYmin = y;
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, mX, (y + mY)/2);
                    }
                } else if (dy > 0) {
                    if (mYmin > y) {
                        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                        mPath.reset();
                        mPath.moveTo(mX, mYmax);
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mYmax, mX, (y + mY) / 2);
                        if (mYmin<mYStart)
                            mYmin = y;
                        else
                            mYmin = mYStart;
                    }
                    else {
                        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, mX, (y + mY) / 2);
                        mYmax = y;
                    }

                }
                mY = y;
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mListView.scrollBy(0, (int) mY);
                    }
                }, 200);

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw

            mPath.reset();
            mCanvas.drawText("10 - 15", mX-30, mYmax, mTextPaint);
            mCanvas.drawText("10 - 15", mX-30, mYmin, mTextPaint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I achieved so far

[image]

How can I complete this? I will also add this as an open source library if everything works. This is the full [source code](https://github.com/vinayakb73/Drag-Time-Range-Picker).

Comment: why are you creating a native component for this instead of implementing this in react native (JS)?

Comment: I failed to create this on react native with flatlist. And also I don't have much experience in react native.

Comment: Maybe you'll find some helpful examples in https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/

Comment: Looks helpful for me

Comment: Hey, did you manage to do it with RNgesture-handler?

Comment: @Carollour yes. and also help of this library https://github.com/SmallStoneSK/react-native-draggable-calendar

Comment: Thanks! I want to do the exact same thing, so I'll take a look :)